# How to get static link from assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new in Rails and still got stuck at get a link to javascript file.
I am using Bower Rails to install `xdLocalStorage` and after installed, a received a folder `xdLocalStorage` at `vendor/assets/bower_component`.

In my `app/assets/javascript/xdLocalStorage/application.js`:

```
//= require xdLocalStorage
//= require_tree .
```

In my `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( xdLocalStorage/application.js )
```

Now, I want to get the url to file in `xdLocalStorage`. But i could not. I had tried as the follow:

```
= asset_url 'xdLocalStorage/dist/scripts/xdLocalStorage.min.js'
```

But it return 404.

Some people ask me why am I have to get url. The `xdLocalStorage.min.js` is not using for my website, it would be embed on another website and dynamically load by jquery. So I need to get url to this file.

And some people ask me why not move xdLocalStorage to public folder. Because I need it is be able to upgrade `xdLocalStorage` by Bower easier.

Please help me to get the above url.
Rails version: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `xdLocalStorage/dist/scripts/xdLocalStorage.min.js` because it is not precompiled. If you need it - add to `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile`, or make a separate manifest for it and also add to `assets.precompile`

Also take into account, that link will change due to asset fingerprinting, so to give a link out you may need a controller action that will redirect to actual one.

Comment: I added for precompile `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( xdLocalStorage/application.js )`.

Comment: Is this OK? After add to precompile, how could I got url?

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh you can only get url for precompiled files, `asset_url('xdLocalStorage/application.js')` for this case. All `require`s are just concatenated inside that file

Comment: Thank you very much